# inserting single and double quotation in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have been using different font on .NET front end, so frequently I encounter quotation as well as double quotation while inserting in sql server. So I am having problem regarding inserting value with both of single and double quotation on the sql server.

Thanks

Comment: an example would help `:D`

Comment: You can simply double up your single/double quotes to escape them, but as @Habib says, use parameters.

Comment: using single or double quotes is only possible in absence of both the quotes but when we have both the quotes as parameter its kind of hard, anyways @Habib's done it right for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> have been using different font on .NET front end

Use [Parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) from .Net. It appears you are concatenating strings to form an insert query.